# Can a supine verb have arguments?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, vergilius, aeneis, supinum

Consider the following line from the *Aeneid*, Book VI:

> nec credere quivi hunc tantum tibi me discessu ferre dolorem.

Context: Aeneas has traveled into the underworld, and bumps into Dido, who he infers has committed suicide because of his departure.

My best literal translation is: "I couldn't believe this, my leaving, to bring unto you such pain," because I think that **me discessu** (for me to leave) stands in apposition with **hunc**. But I'm not sure whether supine verbs can have a subject argument.

So, generally, can an ablative clause formed from a supine verb have nouns corresponding to the base verb's subject or object?

Comment: I would discessu interpret here as a participle, and part of an ablativus absolutus with me ->  because I left.  Your question is still valid though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at it, I don't think *me* is ablative; it's more likely an accusative as the subject of an indirect statement with *credere*. *Discessu* here is not a supine, but a fourth-declension noun, *discessus*.

The translated line should actually be:

> Nor did I believe that I in my departure would ever have caused you so much pain.

(Apologies for the tenses.)

All the grammars are clear that the ablative supine does not take an object of any kind. The *hunc* then probably goes with *tantum dolorem* in a way that can't be literally translated into English without extra words.

Addendum:

I checked two nineteenth-century interlinears to see if they could shed light on it. [Hart/Osborn's](https://books.google.com/books?id=WNAWAAAAYAAJ&pg=171#v=onepage&q&f=false) is very nearly the same as mine, while [Dewey's](https://archive.org/stream/virgilsneidbooks00virg#page/286/mode/2up) differs only in the translation of *hunc*.

Comment: Great to share interpretations here, thanks! me as an accusative in an indirect statement is possible from a grammatical perspective, but the positioning of the words (me discessu) as a group are in favor of an ablativus absolutus. You translate me discessu as my departure. How is this possessive aspect shown in the Latin? If me is an accusative, I would translate discessu as "by going away". But it would seem farfetched to me.

Comment: @piscator No, I translate *discessu* as "in my departure" with *me* being "I". That part has to be the case, otherwise there is no subject of *ferre*.  *me* as an ablative also cannot be apposite to *hunc*, as they're different cases.

Comment: I think *hunc* is the subject of *ferre*. My translation would be "and I could not believe that this caused so much pain to you, after / because I left." How do you translate *hunc*? I must admit it is a difficult choice.

Comment: @piscator I will say that word order has something to recommend your interpretation—strongly, even—but grammatically *me discessu* would be an anomaly if it were a supine clause. I added two other translations to mine above which should clarify usage.

Comment: Do you mean ablative clause (ablativus absolutus) by a supine clause? I could be missing the meaning of supine clause in English. I thought the supine is only referring to the first and second supine, certain verbs ending with -um and -u. I don't think there is a supine in this line of Vergilius.

Comment: @piscator Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your post then. The problem becomes another, then, as *discessu* (with a **-u**) cannot be a regular perfect participle. This is going off your comment that "*me discessu* is an ablative clause." Were that the case, you would have seen *me discesso* along with a very different (sc. passive) meaning!

Comment: You are right, it can not be an ablative absoute, "by going away" is correct. Thanks!

Comment: This makes sense: I am seeing that **me** is at once the object of **credere** and the subject of **ferre**. It's in its accusative form because the embedded clause is a complement of **credere** (whence the infinitive form for **ferre**). I am seeing that with Vergil, the word order is calculated to throw off a learner! Thanks.

Comment: @jlovegren: It may help to keep in mind that the supine is (from) a kind of substantive noun: it's not an adjective and it cannot agree with a noun. It is its case that conexes it with other nouns or adjectives, not agreement. (I agree with Weimer.)

Answer (score 6):

The second supine (ending with -u) can only be combined with adjectives, or with *fas* and *nefas*. Examples:

- *iucundum cognitu atque auditu*
- *nefas est dictu*

A second supine verb never has an object, but it can have a subject, for example *pleraque faciliora sunt dictu quam factu*.